# Power function in T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following returns .81 as expected:

```
select .9*.9;
```

But this does not. Its return value is .8:

```
select power(.9, 2)
```

To have it return .81, I have to cast the input:

```
select power(cast(.9 as float), 2)
```

Why is a cast needed here? What am I missing?

Comment: If you leave "how many decimal places should the result have?" up to SQL Server, it's not always going to make the decision you want. Try expicit decimal (really not float in this case).

Comment: The `power` function takes a *float* as a parameter and returns a *float*, it will be forcing a scale of 1.

Comment: Ms doc says [if first arg type is decimal(p, s) then return type is  decimal(38, s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). s=1 in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `power` function return type is dictated by the data type of the first parameter. Here, you're giving it a `decimal(1,1)`. As noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types), it's returning a `decimal(38,1)`.

You'll get the result you want by either casting, as you've done, or by feeding the function differently.

Answer (score 2):

The scalar value `.9` is a DECIMAL with 1 digit of precision and the same precision is returned.  If you use at least 2 digits of precision you'll get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT POWER(.90, 2);
```

OR

```
DECLARE @num DECIMAL(18,2) = .9;
SELECT POWER(@num, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your passed value will have a default *scale* and *precision* of 1.

You can verify this by using

```
select precision, scale
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'select .9 as test',null,0)
```